# read form elements with php

Tags: php, html

i have a form that contain some input like this

[image]

the `<tr></tr>` code of each line is:

```
<tr id="1">
<td><input id="dp1407131141368" size="18" value="02/03/1393 00:00:01" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" name="starttime[]" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="dp1407131141369" size="18" value="02/03/1393 00:30:00" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" name="endtime[]" type="text"></td>
<td><p id="t1">title 1</p><input value="new title" name="title[]" id="ht1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><p id="e1">comment 1</p><input value="new comment" name="extended[]" id="he1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><p id="s1">short comment</p><input value="new short  comment" name="short[]" id="hs1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><input value="+" style="background-color: green;font-weight: bold;color:white" class="additem" type="button">  <input style="background-color: red;font-weight: bold;color:white" value="X" class="removeitem" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

now i add a new row with jquery like this:

[image]

my new red row code is:

```
<tr style="background-color: #FFDFEF;">
<td><input id="dp1407131141374" size="18" value="" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" name="starttime[]" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="dp1407131141375" size="18" value="" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" name="endtime[]" type="text"></td>
<td><p id="t1">new title</p><input value="new title" name="title[]" id="ht1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><p id="e1">new comment</p><input value="new comment" name="extended[]" id="he1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><p id="s1">new short  comment</p><input value="new short  comment" name="short[]" id="hs1" type="hidden"></td>
<td><input value="+" style="background-color: green;font-weight: bold;color:white" class="additem" type="button">  <input style="background-color: red;font-weight: bold;color:white" value="X" class="removeitem" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

both codes have same `name` attribute, but when i want to read form elements in for each with php just first and last rows fetched, and second row that added with jquery dont fetched

my php code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
foreach ($_POST['starttime'] as $key => $val) {
echo $_POST['title'][$key] . ' - ' .  $_POST['short'][$key] . ' - ' .  $_POST['starttime'][$key] . ' - ' . $_POST['endtime'][$key] . "</br>";
}
}
```

what can i do for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays use keys before values.

Use $array[key][value], like this:

```
$_POST[$key]['title']
```

Comment: thank you but i get this error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\epg\upload.php on line 264` and my echo is just `---` for two time

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and report back on what it shows you.

Comment: when i add rows with jquery, and then see source of page new rows not showed in source.
 i think because of this problem my elements don't show in foreach